# how to invoke a piece of javascript that resides in an HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have in my HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a=2;
</script>
<script src=".../abc.js"/>
```

What I want to do: inside the abc.js file I want to access the variable a:

```
#...inside abc.js
function bar(){
    return a; //How?
}
```

Is this possible/reasonable? No matter how I rephrase my question, I got answers that worked for the other way round, i.e. accessing the external abc.js from within an HTML file...

Comment: Aside from using XML-style self-closing tag syntax for the second script, the code you have in the question will already do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can :

1.if `a` is global :

```
a=2
```

and not:

```
var a=2
```

2.And a also must be declared outside function specially :anonymous function ,

So don't do this :

```
(function(){
   var a=2;
})
```

3.And `abc.js` should be loaded after . as you had did.

Comment: It is declared outside of any function, it is already a global. You don't need to omit the `var` statement.

Comment: worked! either with or without 'var', although IDE complains about not resolving the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This in your abc.js

```
function bar(var1){
result = var1; //do other stuff here
return result;
}
```

and this in your HTML

```
<script src="abc.js"></script> 
<script>
//invoke the bar function and pass it info
var luckynumb = bar(7); //now luckynumb is 7
</script>
```

Comment: The question is asking about accessing the variable `a`, not passing a literal as an argument.